# NSPR emscripten compile assembly file '*.s'

Tags: emscripten

On Compiling NSPR with emscripten, I have encountered a problem.

emscripten don't know ".s" suffix, and emitted the error like

`shared:ERROR: os_Linux_x86.s: Input file has an unknown suffix, don't know what to do with it!`

Alternatively, I have compiled the file with "clang"

`/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspaces/EMC/emsdk/clang/e1.38.20_64bit/clang  -o os_Linux_x86.o      -Wall -pthread -g -fno-inline -fPIC  -UNDEBUG -DDEBUG_xxxxxx -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DDEBUG=1 -DXP_UNIX=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_FILE_LOCKING=1 -DHAVE_POINTER_LOCALTIME_R=1 -DLINUX=1 -DHAVE_DLADDR=1 -DHAVE_LCHOWN=1 -DHAVE_SETPRIORITY=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -DFORCE_PR_LOG -D_PR_PTHREADS -UHAVE_CVAR_BUILT_ON_SEM -D_NSPR_BUILD_ -I../../../../dist/include/nspr -I../../../../pr/include -I../../../../pr/include/private  -c os_Linux_x86.s`

But, "Wanring" has come out,

`shared:WARNING: object /var/folders/6d/cn41t4b56b725ych8k101yd80000gn/T/emscripten_temp_cQDqqw_archive_contents/os_Linux_x86_f787044a.o is not LLVM bitcode, cannot link`

the output file on llvm-nm is like

`0000000000000050 T _PR_x86_AtomicAdd
0000000000000020 T _PR_x86_AtomicDecrement
0000000000000000 T _PR_x86_AtomicIncrement
0000000000000040 T _PR_x86_AtomicSet`

And I have used "emar" for the static library "libnspr4.a", and It works.

But 
`bash-3.2$ /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspaces/EMC/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.20/emcc -D__i386__ -D_PR_POLL_AVAILABLE  abstract.o -Xlinker  -L../../dist/lib -lplc4 -L../../dist/lib -lnspr4 -lpthread -o abstract.js
shared:WARNING: object /var/folders/6d/cn41t4b56b725ych8k101yd80000gn/T/emscripten_temp_HXB1yC_archive_contents/os_Linux_x86_f787044a.o is not LLVM bitcode, cannot link
shared:WARNING: object /var/folders/6d/cn41t4b56b725ych8k101yd80000gn/T/emscripten_temp_HXB1yC_archive_contents/os_Linux_x86_f787044a.o is not LLVM bitcode, cannot link
shared:WARNING: object /var/folders/6d/cn41t4b56b725ych8k101yd80000gn/T/emscripten_temp_HXB1yC_archive_contents/os_Linux_x86_f787044a.o is not LLVM bitcode, cannot link
error: undefined symbol: _PR_x86_AtomicDecrement
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use`-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0
`error: undefined symbol: _PR_x86_AtomicIncrement
error: undefined symbol: _PR_x86_AtomicSet
error: undefined symbol: pthread_attr_getschedparam
error: undefined symbol: pthread_attr_setinheritsched
error: undefined symbol: pthread_attr_setscope
error: undefined symbol: sched_get_priority_max
error: undefined symbol: sched_get_priority_min
error: undefined symbol: sendfile
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
shared:ERROR: '/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspaces/EMC/emsdk/node/8.9.1_64bit/bin/node /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspaces/EMC/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.20/src/compiler.js /tmp/tmpAycNjj.txt /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspaces/EMC/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.20/src/library_pthread_stub.js' failed (1)`

I guess that the output static library is not linked with "os_Linux_x86 functions"

I need your comment. Thanks

---

additionally,

command "llvm-nm libnspr4.a" shows

`U __errno_location
         U _pr_CopyLowBits
-------- d coOpenDevURandom
-------- d fdDevURandom
         U gettimeofday
         U open
         U read
uxshm_568a7427.o:
         U PR_Assert
         U PR_Calloc
         U PR_Close
         U PR_CreateFileMap
         U PR_Free
         U PR_GetCurrentThread
         U PR_GetOSError
         U PR_GetOpenFileInfo64
         U PR_ImportFile
         U PR_LogPrint
         U PR_Malloc
         U PR_SetError
         U PR_smprintf
         U PR_smprintf_free
         U PR_snprintf
         U PR_sscanf
-------- T _MD_AttachSharedMemory
-------- T _MD_CloseSharedMemory
-------- T _MD_DeleteSharedMemory
-------- T _MD_DetachSharedMemory
-------- T _MD_OpenSharedMemory
         U _MD_unix_map_close_error
         U _MD_unix_map_default_error
         U _MD_unix_map_open_error
         U _MD_unix_map_unlink_error
         U _PR_MakeNativeIPCName
         U __errno_location
-------- T _md_ExportFileMapAsString
-------- T _md_ImportFileMapFromString
-------- T _md_OpenAnonFileMap
         U _pr_shm_lm
         U _pr_shma_lm
         U close
         U ftok
         U ftruncate
         U getpid
         U open
         U shmat
         U shmctl
         U shmdt
         U shmget
         U strcpy
         U strlen
         U unlink
uxwrap_0bf9337c.o:
linux_b243132c.o:
-------- T _MD_CleanupBeforeExit
-------- T _MD_EarlyInit
-------- T _MD_HomeGCRegisters
         U _MD_unix_terminate_waitpid_daemon
libnspr4.a(os_Linux_x86_f787044a.o):
0000000000000050 T _PR_x86_AtomicAdd
0000000000000020 T _PR_x86_AtomicDecrement
0000000000000000 T _PR_x86_AtomicIncrement
0000000000000040 T _PR_x86_AtomicSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it won't.

WebAssembly itself is a target platform, meaning it is equivalent to assembly in the web. The compiler will never convert native x86 assembly code (`.s`) to another target platform.

I don't think compiling such low-level system library like NSPR to WebAssembly would a good idea because WebAssembly currently don't have system features such as pthread (well, Chrome supports it but it is yet experimental feature and disabled by default).

Speaking of clang, you should set a compiler flag `--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm` in order to compile it to WebAssembly. Cloudflare has [a good example](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-workers-wasm-demo/blob/master/Makefile) on how to use clang for WebAssembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. 
Unfortunately, NSPR has only not "os_Linux_x86.c" but "os_Linux_x86.s".
And I need to make a static library "libnspr4.a" linked with "os_Linux_x86.s".

It says that "os_Linux_x86.o is not LLVM bitcode, cannot link".

is it not possible to compile "os_Linux_x86.s" to "os_Linux_x86.o"?

Comment: @MarcoJo I'm not familiar with NSPR but there might be pure C/C++ implementation that targets a platform other than x86. Emscripten will always throw errors as long as there is native ASM code in `.a` at linker stage. If using the ASM file `.s` is mandatory you have no choice but to use a disassembler that converts an ASM file to C source code, or you re-write these parts to C.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you need NSPR in browsers? There might be an alternative...

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't tell you why I need to do this. But I need :(
I will try disassembling. Thank you Bumsik.